# Remove Brackets and Parentheses from string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like this

```
string = 'LVPV(filler)PITN(notneeded)ATLDQITGK[0;0;0;0;0;6;2;0;0;5;0]'
```

How do I remove everything in the brackets and parentheses? Like so:

string = 'LVPVPITNATLDQITGK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression is ideal for these tasks and fortunately python standard library provides support for regex

```
>>> re.sub(r"[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", st)
'LVPVPITNATLDQITGK'
```

The above pattern substitutes with empty string any thing that is within a  parenthesis or bracket block.

**Note** Regex patterns are difficult to make robust and can easily digress and break for exceptional patterns like

```
'LVPV(filler]PITN[notneeded)ATLDQITGK[0;0;0;0;0;6;2;0;0;5;0]'
```

So you need to be certain about your input data and its expected output

And nevertheless, you can always do this without regex

```
>>> import string
>>> ''.join(st.translate(string.maketrans("()[]"," "*4)).split(' ')[::2])
'LVPVPITNATLDQITGK'
```

Comment: what if I have a string like this s = "var = {{some data },{some css(css) and data } Required data (dummy){scripts}" how can i only extract RequiredData

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use alternation operator.

```
>>> string = 'LVPV(filler)PITN(notneeded)ATLDQITGK[0;0;0;0;0;6;2;0;0;5;0]'
>>> re.sub(r"\([^()]*\)|\[[^\[\]]*\]", "", string)
'LVPVPITNATLDQITGK'
>>> st = 'LVPV(filler]PITN[notneeded)ATLDQITGK[0;0;0;0;0;6;2;0;0;5;0]'
>>> re.sub(r"\([^()]*\)|\[[^\[\]]*\]", "", st)
'LVPVATLDQITGK'
```